# Cannot delete a file Java 8

Tags: java-8, delete-file, file-rename

I have a file that I open with a buffered reader, I can read from it without any issues. When done I do a close(), then a 2 second delay, and last a delete on the file without any success. When I verify the file it is apparently still held By Java. Please help me, I'm getting desperate.

Here is my code :

```
    public static void deleteLine(String inFileName, String line) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String tmpFileName = inFileName+"tmp";
    File inFile = new File(inFileName);
    File tmpFile = new File(tmpFileName);
    String r;

    if (tmpFile.exists())
    {
        tmpFile.delete();
    }

    if (inFile.exists())
    {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile)))
        {            
            r = br.readLine();

            while (r != null)
            {                
                if (r.equals(line))
                {                                     
                    System.out.println("removing line "+r);                                      
                }
                else
                {
                    //MyFile.append(tmpFileName, r);
                }

                r = br.readLine();                
            }
        }                

        if (inFile.delete())
        {
            System.out.println("Delete Succesful");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Delete Failed!");
        }

        System.out.println("Renaming temp file "+tmpFileName+" to "+inFileName);            
        if (tmpFile.renameTo(inFile))
        {       
            System.out.println("Rename Successful");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Rename Failed!");
        }
    }

}
```

And here is MyFile.append

```
public static void append(String file,String line) throws IOException
    {   
        File f = new File(file);
        if(!f.exists()){
           System.out.println("Created file "+file);
           f.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw) ;
        System.out.println("Writing "+line+" to file "+file);
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();
    }
```

Comment: what is `MyFile`?

Comment: MyFile is a source file that I created with functions to make my life easier.  In this instance it's called to append a line to my temporary file <fileTmp>.  I don't believe it is the issue since it only works with the temporary file and not the file I wish to delete. But in case here is it's code :

Comment: no im pretty aware that it is not the issue, but since you have not provided runnable code, i need to ask what it is.

Comment: please dont post code in the comments, it is absolutely unreadable. Update your original question with the edit command if you feel the need to add more information.

Comment: Oh and I mean I don't think it's the issue, but I don't claim to be sure. I appreciate your help and was only attempting to help my helper

Comment: I updated my Question to include MyFile.Append

Comment: first of all your code is very, very messy, second of all, you are ignoring the return from `fr.delete()`. Third there is no creating of the file, so are you even allowed to delete the file? user rights?

Comment: Yes, I am not a professional coder, and I have been trying all kinds of things to figure out why it does not work.  I have added some code to verify if the file is deleted or not.  if fr.delete() is true then success else it's a fail.  It fails systematically.  As for user rights, the user Everyone in windows has total control over the file.  I have tried opening it in wordpad, modifying it and saving.  If my program is running and has attempted to delete the file, wordpad tells me it is already opened in Javaw.  to me it's as if br.close() never really closes the file.

Comment: `close()` will always release but since you are using multiple readers/writers and we are not seeing your entire code you have a so called leak somewhere. best practice is to always use a try-resource-block when dealing with buffers. `try (BufferedReader reader = 
       new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/foo.txt"))) { // code here }` since this will automatically close the stream when it exits the block. You dont have to call close.

Comment: you can read about it here https://www.baeldung.com/java-buffered-reader#3-closing-the-stream

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.  Also, I have attempted to clean my code a bit.

Comment: Thank you, I have sourrounded all my bufferedreaders in a try-resource-block.  Now it works.  I am very grateful.

Comment: As a side note, it is very inefficient to reopen the file for every line you want to write. Why don’t you open one writer at the beginning, just like the reader and close it when you done, just like the reader?